# table caption not left aligned

Tags: tables, captions, two-column, alignment

I am working on a article and using LATEX two column mode for Elsevier. There is one wide table which must be fitted into two column. I used table* but the caption of the table is not left aligned. How can I solve this?

```
\begin{table*}[]
\centering
\caption{}
\label{tab:my-table}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{lccccccccc}
\hline
& \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Title} & \multicolumn{1}{l} 
{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} 
& \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\ \cline{3-4}
Title 1 & Title 1 & Title 1 & Title 1 & Title 1 & Title 1 & Title 1 & 
Title 1 & Title 1 & Title 1 \\ \hline
Researcher1 & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx 
& xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx \\
Researcher1 & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx 
& xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx \\
Researcher1 & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx 
& xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx \\
Researcher1 & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx 
& xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx \\
Researcher1 & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx 
& xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx \\
Researcher1 & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx 
& xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{xxxxxxx}} & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & 
xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table*}
```

Thanks in advance.

[image: table]

Comment: As always on this site you are miøuch more likely to get help if you provide a full but minimal example that show your problem and which others can copy an test as is. Note: if you're using non standard classes, please provide a link to that class.

Comment: Which documentclass do you use? Please make your code compilable. (See also: [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)). Do you get any error messages upon compiling your code? If yo, which?

Comment: Most likely unrelated to the alignment issue, but please be aware that using `\resizebox` on a table will result in inconsistent font sizes throughout the document. There are better alternatives to make sure a table fits into the available space.

Comment: I dont get any error. \documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/591883, seems to be your question duplicate to it.

Comment: @Zarko Thank you very much! I solved it!

Comment: Glad to heir this. You may consider tor wrote an answer (in form of MWE: Minimal Working Example) on your question to show us, how you solve your problem. This will be helpful to people with similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

Quit late answer, but hopefully it may help someone :-)

Answer, which provide OP, unfortunately doesn't provide information, haw he tested it. Therefore his claims cannot be confirmed, even worse, testing it in standard document example using `article` document class show, that it is false:

- The first code line in code fragment `\begin{table*}[width=\textwidth]` contain error. To `\begin{table}` can follow only placement options, for example `[htbp]`. However,
  `\begin{table*}` is always on the top of the next page where table is inserted, consequently any placement option is not considered.
- On caption position can be influenced, if is used `caption` or similar package. Using `caption`, example of option wgich push cation to the left side of table can be:

```
\usepackage[skip=1ex, % vertical space between caption and table
            singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
```

- use of the `\resizebox{...}` should bbe avoide as much as possible (since it make font size in table inconsistent with fonts out of table). Better is prescribed table width.

Possible MWE, which solve OP problem, can be:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[skip=1ex,
            singlelinecheck=false]{caption}

%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
    \centering
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\caption{Caption text}
\label{tab:my-table}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} lccccccccc}
    \hline
    &   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Title} 
                &   &   &   &   &       \\
    \cline{3-4}
Title 1 & Title 2 & Title 3 & Title 4 & Title 5 
        & Title 6 & Title 7 & Title 8 & Title 9 
        & Title 10          \\ 
    \hline
Researcher 1 
        & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx 
        & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx 
        & xxxxxxx \\
Researcher 2
        & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx
        & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx
        & xxxxxxx \\
Researcher 3
        & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx
        & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx
        & xxxxxxx \\
Researcher 4
        & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx
        & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx
        & xxxxxxx \\
Researcher 5
        & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx
        & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx
        & xxxxxxx \\
Researcher 6
        & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx
        & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx
        & xxxxxxx \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{xxxxxxx}} 
        & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx
        & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx
        & xxxxxxx \\
    \hline
\end{tabular*}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

where distance between columns is left to LaTeX (to macro `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}`). Result of compilation is

[image: -]

(red lines indicate text borders).

Another possible solution is use `tabularray` package (with library `booktabs`, which load package of the same name) and manulay set of distance between columns:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
  \ExplSyntaxOn
\NewChildSelector{eachthree}
  {
    \int_step_inline:nnnn {6}{3}{\l_tblr_childs_total_tl}
      { \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tblr_childs_clist {##1} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage[skip=1ex,
            singlelinecheck=false]{caption}

%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document


\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
\caption{Caption text}
\small  % <---
\label{tab:my-table}
\begin{tblr}{width=\textwidth,
             colsep = 3pt,   % <---
             colspec = {@{} l *{9}{X[c]}@{}},
             row{3-Z}={rowsep=0pt},
             row{eachthree} = {abovesep=1ex},
             }
    \toprule
    &   & \SetCell[c=2]{c}  Title 
            &   &   &   &   &   &       \\
    \cmidrule{3-4}
Title 1 & Title 2 & Title 3 & Title 4 & Title 5
        & Title 6 & Title 7 & Title 8 & Title 9
        & Title 10          \\
    \midrule
Researcher 1
        & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx
        & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx
        & xxxxxxx \\
Researcher 2
        & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx
        & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx
        & xxxxxxx \\
Researcher 3
        & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx
        & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx
        & xxxxxxx \\
Researcher 4
        & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx
        & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx
        & xxxxxxx \\
Researcher 5
        & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx
        & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx
        & xxxxxxx \\
Researcher 6
        & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx
        & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx
        & xxxxxxx \\
\SetCell{c,font=\bfseries} xxxxxxx 
        & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx
        & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx
        & xxxxxxx \\
    \hline
\end{tblr}%
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I added "**[width=\textwidth]**" and table caption justified left.

```
\begin{table*}[width=\textwidth]
\centering
\caption{}
\label{tab:my-table}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{lccccccccc}
\hline
& \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Title} & \multicolumn{1}{l} 
{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} 
& \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\ \cline{3-4}
Title 1 & Title 1 & Title 1 & Title 1 & Title 1 & Title 1 & Title 1 & 
Title 1 & Title 1 & Title 1 \\ \hline
Researcher1 & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx 
& xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx \\
Researcher1 & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx 
& xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx \\
Researcher1 & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx 
& xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx \\
Researcher1 & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx 
& xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx \\
Researcher1 & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx 
& xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx \\
Researcher1 & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx 
& xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{xxxxxxx}} & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & 
xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx & xxxxxxx \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table*}
```